# How does the default SceneKit application in Xcode handle the double click?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, scenekit

When I open a game application in Xcode, and go to SceneKit there is already some code written. The code draws an airplane and allows the user to rotate it. When you double tap anywhere on the screen the plane returns to its original position.  How can you do that. I looked through the whole application and there is no hint of a double tap gesture or bringing the view back to its position. How does that happen without any code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no code there to allow you to rotate the plane either.

That functionality as well as the double tap to reset the camera functionality is added by the `scnView.allowsCameraControl = YES` line in the view controller.